# Simulink - running parallel simulations

Tags: cluster, matlab, parallel-processing

Is it possible to run Simulink calculations in parallel mode on cluster? And if its possible then what actually Simulink do when number of processes that i need is more than cluster has nodes? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Parallel Computing Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/parallel-computing/) from MathWorks (the page has links to the documentation).

This is a quick how-to to start: http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-6GRUQ3/index.html?product=DM&solution=1-6GRUQ3

I don't know what is the exact behavior of this toolbox when there are more processes than nodes but it's in its documentation for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Normally when you add blocks, the program is executed in a linear fashion - single thread.
So first you would need to setup your model for multitasking. https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/implement-task-parallelism-in-simulink.html
But that has to run on a single machine.

Unless you want to simply run the same program multiple times but with different inputs, then it is easy using Parallel toolbox https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/example-of-parallel-simulations-workflow.html